# MVC Remote Validation accessing field from class above

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In the below code I cannot pass the username to the remote validation function:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }

public class Numbers
{


            [Display(Name = "Additonal Numbers")]
            [Remote("NumberExists", "Account", AdditionalFields = "UserName", ErrorMessage = "Serial is already taken.")]
            public string additionalNumbers { get; set; }
 }


public List<Numbers> NumberList { get; set; }
```

This is a simple example but I would like to pass additional fields from the same model within a list but I cant seem to access anything outside the scope of the public class.

Do I need to pass the rest of the model into the list in some way to achieve this or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Why are you set this nested class ??!! Just add the `additionalNumbers` property to the above class and everything will be good :)

Comment: How do you achieve this?

Comment: `UserName` Property should be in the same class of the `additionalNumbers` property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AdditionalFields` parameter in the remote validation attribute need to be in the same class as the object being validated.

..edit..

```
public class Numbers
{

            public string UserName { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Additonal Numbers")]
            [Remote("NumberExists", "Account", AdditionalFields = "UserName", ErrorMessage = "Serial is already taken.")]
            public string additionalNumbers { get; set; }
 }
```

..edit after comments..
It looks like what you want to do is validate that all the numbers are unique for a Username. Try this:

```
public string UserName { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Additonal Numbers")]
[Remote("NumberExists", "Account", AdditionalFields = "UserName", ErrorMessage = "Serial is already taken.")]
public List<String> NumberList { get; set; }
```

In your NumberExists Action take a List of Strings rather than only 1 string. This will let you validate your whole array all at once.

```
Public ActionResult NumberExists(List<String> NumberList, String UserName){
    //Validate list is unique for username
}
```

Comment: Sure, I moved the UserName field into the same class as your additionalNumbers field.

Comment: Yes but additionalNumbers needs to be a list of numbers?

Comment: Great nearly there. When I add @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberList}) twice I only see the first entry and it doesn't seem to build a list?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberList[0]}) & @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberList[1]})  doesn't seem to kick off the validation at all?

Comment: Hmm, the Validation Signature might actually be Public ActionResult NumberExists(String NumberList, String UserName), you might have to take a look at the ajax request the browser is making. What does firebug say?

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberList}) makes the request but it is always the first instance of the textbox value that get sent? @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberList[0]}) not get request is made at all

Answer (score 0):

`UserName` Property should be in the same class of the `additionalNumbers` property:

```
public class NumbersViewModel
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }

   [Display(Name = "Additonal Numbers")]
   [Remote("NumberExists", "Account", AdditionalFields = "UserName", ErrorMessage = "Serial is already taken.")]
   public string additionalNumbers { get; set; }

   public List<Numbers> NumberList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes but additionalNumbers needs to be a list of numbers?

Comment: public List<String> NumberList { get; set; } if I add two @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.NumberList}) to the view I one get the data from the first

Comment: This isn't related to your question. Anyway try to do this `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.NumberList)` Should work.